# How to make a cutoff in CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to make something like this in pure css?

[image]

I completely do not have idea how to do it. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You should check css clipping and masking. This is a great article about it on [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) and also [this](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) clip-path maker should be helpful.